# Pytorch CNN with demonstrated architecture will learn, but accuracy won't increase

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pytorch

My Pytorch CNN runs and learns but the accuracy doesn't improve. The train loss decreases, but when testing on the **train** set, it has random accuracy. I implemented the same architecture in Keras and I had 90%+ accuracy. I'm basically just wondering if there's something clearly wrong in my structure. Here it is:

```
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, 3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(5*5*64, 1024) 
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024, 2048)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(2048, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2, 2))
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), (2, 2))
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv3(x)), (2, 2))

        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1) 
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, 0.5)
        x = F.sigmoid(self.fc3(x))
        return x
```

loss_function = nn.BCELoss()

Comment: Make sure you are normalizing your input data. And without seeing more of your code like dataloader part, and which dataset you are using, it might be difficult to find if something is wrong.

Comment: are you using the same optimizer and same meta parameters as in keras? (specifically, the same learning rate?)

Comment: There's nothing fundamentally wrong with the structure. The problem is likely somewhere else. If you're getting good accuracy during training but bad accuracy when evaluating the same data again then the problem is probably somewhere in the differences between how you sample and preprocess during training and test. If you post more of your code we may be able to help more.